# Singular of Plural verb after I followed by name

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which one is correct? I followed by name takes singular or plural verb?

> 1. I, John Bolton, deposes and says the following.
> 2. I, John Bolton, depose and say the following.

Comment: The verb should agree with the pronoun 'I'.

Comment: I, Michael Harvey, hop, skip and jump.

Comment: You should rethink your terminology.  The verbs in "I depose" and "Bolton deposes" are *both singular*.  So the verb is singular regardless of which one is correct.  In this case, "depose" is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of the single comma in the example sentences in the question is nonstandard.

However, the verb will end up being the same in this specific case regardless of whether *I, John Bolton* describes one person or two people:

1. I, John Bolton, *depose* and *say* the following.
2. I and John Bolton *depose* and *say* the following.
   (Conventionally, it would be *John Bolton and I*, but there's nothing wrong with the reverse order.)
   *but*

- John Bolton ***deposes and says*** the following.

---

Only the third-person-singular conjugation of verbs use a different form:

- I depose and say.
- We depose and say.
- You depose and say.
- They depose and say.
- Two people depose and say.
- He / she / it ***deposes and says***.
- One person ***deposes and says***.

Note that, depending on the verb, the form of the third-person-singular conjugation will change. For instance, it's *I carry* and *it carries* (not *it carrys*).